# How do I get different methods in main to interact with each other when they are previously called?

Tags: java, methods

I called several different methods in the main method, which is essentially a "composite" version of the file, combining those existing methods into one method. Each method that gets called in the main method has its own unique properties that are defined outside of the main method in the same file. There are 5 methods in main, and each of them are defined outside of the main method with int and Strings that are defined on the class level.

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
        public class Chapter5 
        {
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int randomNumber1, randomNumber2, randomNumber3, randomNumber4, randomNumber5, randomNumber6;

        int counter = 0;

        int userInput1 = scan.nextInt();
        int userInput2 = scan.nextInt();
        int userInput3 = scan.nextInt();
        int userInput4 = scan.nextInt();
        int userInput5 = scan.nextInt();
        int userInput6 = scan.nextInt();

        int numberMatch = 0;
        int matchingIndex;

        public void main(String[] args)
        {
          GenerateRandomNumber();
          IsDuplicateNumber();
          GetUserInput();
          ValidateUserInputNumber();
          OutputResult();
        }

        public int GenerateRandomNumber(){

              randomNumber1 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
              randomNumber2 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
              randomNumber3 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
              randomNumber4 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
              randomNumber5 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
              randomNumber6 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1; 
              return GenerateRandomNumber();
            }

    public boolean IsDuplicateNumber() {
      if (randomNumber2 == randomNumber1) {
        randomNumber2 = (int)(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
        return true;}
      else if (randomNumber3 == randomNumber1 || randomNumber3 == randomNumber2){
        randomNumber3 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
        return true;}
      else if (randomNumber4 == randomNumber1 || randomNumber4 == randomNumber2 || randomNumber4 == randomNumber3){
              randomNumber4 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
              return true;}
      else if (randomNumber5 == randomNumber1 || randomNumber5 == randomNumber2 || randomNumber5 == randomNumber3 || randomNumber5 == randomNumber4){
              randomNumber5 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
              return true;}
      else if (randomNumber6 == randomNumber1 || randomNumber6 == randomNumber2 || randomNumber6 == randomNumber3 || randomNumber6 == randomNumber4 || randomNumber6 == randomNumber5){
              randomNumber6 = (int) (Math.random() * 60) + 1;
              return true;}
      return true;
    }

    public void GetUserInput() {

          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
          userInput1 = scan.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
          userInput2 = scan.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
          userInput3 = scan.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
          userInput4 = scan.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
          userInput5 = scan.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-60: ");
          userInput6 = scan.nextInt();
    }

    public boolean ValidateUserInputNumber() {

      if (userInput1 > 60 || userInput1 < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");}
      if (userInput2 > 60 || userInput2 < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");}
      if (userInput3 > 60 || userInput3 < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");}
      if (userInput4 > 60 || userInput4 < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");}
      if (userInput5 > 60 || userInput5 < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");}
      if (userInput6 > 60 || userInput6 < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");}

      if (userInput2 == userInput1)
        while(userInput2 == userInput1)
      {
        System.out.println("Duplicate");
        userInput2 = scan.nextInt();
      }
      if (userInput3  == userInput1 || userInput3 == userInput2)
        while(userInput3  == userInput1 || userInput3 == userInput2)
      {
        System.out.println("Duplicate");
        userInput3=scan.nextInt();
      }
      if (userInput4 == userInput1 || userInput4 == userInput2 || userInput4 == userInput3)
        while(userInput4 == userInput1 || userInput4 == userInput2 || userInput4 == userInput3)
      {
        System.out.println("Duplicate");
        userInput4=scan.nextInt();
      }
      if (userInput5 == userInput1 || userInput5 == userInput2 || userInput5 == userInput3 || userInput5 == userInput4)
        while(userInput5 == userInput1 || userInput5 == userInput2 || userInput5 == userInput3 || userInput5 == userInput4)
      {
        System.out.println("Duplicate");
        userInput5=scan.nextInt();
      }
       if (userInput6 == userInput1 || userInput6 == userInput2 || userInput6 == userInput3 || userInput6 == userInput4 || userInput6 == userInput5)
        while(userInput6 == userInput1 || userInput6 == userInput2 || userInput6 == userInput3 || userInput6 == userInput4 || userInput6 == userInput5)
      {
        System.out.println("Duplicate");
        userInput6=scan.nextInt();
      }
      return true;
    }

    public int OutputResult() {
      getNumOfMatches();
     if (userInput1 == randomNumber1 || userInput2 == randomNumber2 || 
    userInput3 == randomNumber3 || userInput4 == randomNumber4 || userInput5 == 
    randomNumber5 || userInput6 == randomNumber6) {
                System.out.println("Exact match: you win $1,000,000");
            }
            else if (5 == getNumOfMatches()) {
                System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $100,000");
            }
            else if (4 == getNumOfMatches()) {
                System.out.println("Match all digits: you win $8,000");
            }
            else if (3 == getNumOfMatches()) {
                System.out.println("Match three digits: you win $20");
            }
            else if (2 == getNumOfMatches()) {
                System.out.println("Match two digits: you win $6");
            }
            else if (1 == getNumOfMatches()) {
                System.out.println("Match two digit: you win $2");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, no match; $0");
            }
      return OutputResult();
```

Furthermore, I have two methods that are invoked within the pre-existing methods. They are both called in the method OutputResult();

```
      public boolean foundInLottery(int uInput)
        {
          if(uInput == randomNumber1 || uInput == randomNumber2 
                    || uInput == randomNumber3 || uInput == randomNumber4 
                    || uInput == randomNumber5 || uInput == randomNumber6)
            return true;
          else
            return false;
        }

        public int getNumOfMatches()
        {
          int iMatches = 0;
          if (foundInLottery(userInput1)) { iMatches =iMatches + 1 ;}
          if (foundInLottery(userInput2)) { iMatches =iMatches + 1 ;}
          if (foundInLottery(userInput3)) { iMatches =iMatches + 1 ;}
          if (foundInLottery(userInput4)) { iMatches =iMatches + 1 ;}
          if (foundInLottery(userInput5)) { iMatches =iMatches + 1 ;}
          if (foundInLottery(userInput6)) { iMatches =iMatches + 1 ;}

           return iMatches;
        }
```

This program does compile with no errors or warnings, but when it runs, the message in the output window says

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: A `NullPointerException` is a runtime error, which is why it does not show any errors or warnings before running but only when running.

Comment: Maybe not be the problem you're asking about, but `GenerateRandomNumber()` and `OutputResult()` both have infinite recursions.

Comment: `main` must be a `static` method. Make it `static`, and fix the compilation errors that causes.

Comment: Follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names should start with lowercase.